# React native tree select component

Tags: react-native, treeview, multi-select, multi-level

I tried to find tree view select in react native, But, I couldn't find any. I also tried to generate my own, but it will take more time to develop and need to fix many things that I can't do right now.

Can anybody provide inputs on which library or component use for tree multi-select inputs?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It looks like you are on your own. Maybe, you can share it with the community after you create one.

Comment: @vijayst That means I have to climb Everest on my own! Any suggestion or points to keep in mind for the better journey?